# Why the split function results the ' '?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
k='h==j==u'.split('=',maxsplit=-1)
print(k)
```

the result is:

`['h', '', 'j', '', 'u']`

Can anyone explain me the `''` in the list? I thought the result will be `['h=','j=','u']` or something doesn't have the `''`. I have tried `rsplit` and the `maxsplit` number but it's still the same, except for `maxsplit=1`.

Comment: Because ```split(...)``` splits by EVERY delimiter, including if splitter elements are empty. You would get 2 empty elements in a row for "===".

Comment: Also, the default value for `maxsplit` is already -1, so it is useless in your case.

Comment: If you want something like `['h', 'j', 'u']` as result, you can use `re.split()` like this `re.split('=+', 'h==j==u')`.

Comment: Can you add more test cases? (e.g. given specific inputs what output do you expect)

Answer (score 1):

The empty line `''` is the element between `=` and `=` in `==`.

You can filter it if it bother you:

```
[x for x in "a=b==c".split('=') if x != '']
```

If you are looking for only true values:

```
[x for x in "a=b==c".split('=') if x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI7pCIS2/SKFCITNPQSnRNsnWNllJr7ggJ7NEQ91WXVMhMw0op2iroK4eq/n/PwA)